# Python Requests Giving Me Missing Metadata When Trying To Upload Attachment

Tags: python, python-requests, attachment

I am trying to upload an attachment via an API. I can make it work in the software's Swagger environment with this:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://demo.citywidesolutions.com/v4_server/external/v1/maintenance/service_requests/9/attached_files' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 123456789' \
  -F 'description=' \
  -F 'data=@This is my file.pdf;type=application/pdf'
```

When I try to do the same with python requests I get a 400 error with a message of missing metadata. Here is what I am trying to pass with Python:

```
import requests
Headers = {'accept': '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization': 'Bearer 123456789'}
Attachment = {'description': '', 'data': open('C:/This is my file.pdf', 'rb')}
Response = requests.post(url='https://demo.citywidesolutions.com/v4_server/external/v1/maintenance/service_requests/9/attached_files', headers=Headers, files=Attachment)
```

From that I get a 400 response and the JSON says Missing Metadata. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try explicitly setting the file type in your code; you do so in the curl method, but not in the Python script.

Also, the `requests` library is able to handle 'Content-Type', so typically you don't need to set it. And the description parameter may be expected as a tuple. Here are all those changes; I have not tested since I do not have access to the endpoint:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 123456789'
} # excluded content-type

files = {
    'description': (None, ''),
    'data': ('blank.pdf', open('blank.pdf', 'rb'), 'application/pdf') #added application/pdf format
}

url = 'https://demo.citywidesolutions.com/v4_server/external/v1/maintenance/service_requests/9/attached_files'

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
```

Comment: Thanks! If I leave out the content-type in the header, then I get an error of requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). If I add it back I still get the same missing metadata error.

Comment: Wow you got it! Had to fiddle with it for a bit but finally got it! It was just hating that content-type in the header. Thanks enjoy the bounty!

Comment: @CodyBrown First bounty of my career! Glad you got it working. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the issue here is that you are providing an object as you data.

The `open()` function will return a bufferedReader object and not the actual data of the file.

See:

```
>>> open("README.md", 'rb')
<_io.BufferedReader name='README.md'>
```

I think you can fix this by changing

```py
Attachment = {'description': '', data=open('C:/This is my file.pdf', 'rb')}
```

to

```py
Attachment = {'description': '', data=open('C:/This is my file.pdf', 'rb').read()}
```

Also note that it is normally best practice to have your variable names all in lowercase.

If that does not work then you can try using the files parameter of `post()` like this:

```py
>>> url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

(Example shamelessly stolen from https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Comment: Thanks for this, great idea, but still getting the missing metadata 400 response with this now:

`Headers = {'accept': '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Authorization': 'Bearer 123456789'}
Attachment = {'description': '', 'data': open('C:/This is my file.pdf', 'rb').read()}
Response = requests.post(url='https://demo.citywidesolutions.com/v4_server/external/v1/maintenance/service_requests/9/attached_files', headers=Headers, files=Attachment)`

Perhaps I am missing the @ or the ;type=application/pdf in the data, but I have no idea how to format like that.

Comment: Please see the updated answer there is another option you can try

Comment: Ahh still getting the same error. Has to be with the metadata being -F 'data=@This is my file.pdf;type=application/pdf' in the CURL. If you have any other suggestions I'd love to hear them. Thanks!